# Removing old public keys Part2

Tags: electrum

I've managed to create a wallet with some old private keys from Armory.

After verifying that there are no funds on these addresses, I've closed Electrum
and deleted all files in `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\wallets\` and the config file. The cache folder was empty.

After restarting Electrum and creating a NEW wallet the old addresses (and Keys) where still there.

- Where are these keys stored?
- How can I remove these old addresses?

In the answer to [Removing old public keys](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18684/removing-old-public-keys/18721?newreg=e6d97b29e6c84a3793255891846f12e8) @rdymac writes something about
"second click options". I was not able to find informations about this option.

Clicking an address a second time or double clicking gives no result.
Right-click doesn't give the option to delete the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After restarting Electrum and creating a NEW wallet the old addresses (and Keys) where still there.

So you went through the process of creating a new wallet? You got asked what wallet type you wanted to create, you chose standard wallet, a seed was generated and displayed and then in the step after that you were asked to re-enter the seed to confirm that you wrote it down properly. After that it asks you to enter a password if you like. You did all this?

If you created a new wallet file then it should not contain your old addresses. The only way it can contain your old addresses are:

- the old wallet file is still on your hard drive and you have that opened. you can switch wallet files via file > open or file  > recently open. it's also possible to specify a specific wallet file via the -w command line switch. For example `c:\path\to\electrum.exe -w c:\path\to\wallet`. If you don't specify a specific wallet file it'll open the default_wallet file in the \Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\wallets folder
- you have a malware infection and those addresses aren't really yours. they belong to the malware author and the malware is injecting all your wallets with those addresses in the hope that you will send bitcoin to them.

Also note that public keys are not private keys. You imported armory private keys not public keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I expected the addresse tab to be initially empty - without further checking I've assumed to see the old addresses. Excuse me. However the question of how to delete single IMPORTED address/key is still open.

Comment: You can only import private keys in wallets created specifically for that purpose. You cannot import them into standard deterministic wallets. If you created a wallet specifically using imported private keys you can delete them by going to view > show addresses, switching to addresses tab, right clicking on the corresponding address and choose to remove from the wallet. See the screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/waspBZE.png).